# Update the Ng-Pattern using Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-pattern

Can someone help me how to update the Ng-Pattern using Jquery

I have gone through below question but didn't help me(Most of the Question are related to updating to dynamic values using Angular JS)

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900308/angularjs-dynamic-ng-pattern-validation)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043768/angular-dynamic-ngpattern)
3. [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196903/dynamic-validation-using-ng-pattern-angularjs)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="width: 50px;" id="hourmain">
    <span ng-show="addItem.Hour.$error.pattern">The number must be between 0-4</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Hour" ng-model="form.Hour" placeholder="Hour" required="required" ng-pattern="/^[0-4]+(\.[5]{1})?$/" step="0.5" min="0" max="3" maxlength="3" id="hour">
</div>
```

Now using Jquery How Can I update the ng-pattern value to `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[5]{1})?$/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **jQuery**, you can grab the specific element using:

```
var input = $('input[name="Hour"]');
```

and then set the value of the `ng-pattern` attribute, using:

```
input.attr('ng-pattern', '/^[0-9]+(\.[5]{1})?$/');
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var input = $('input[name="Hour"]');
input.attr('ng-pattern', '/^[0-9]+(\.[5]{1})?$/');

console.log('input ng-pattern is now: ' + input.attr('ng-pattern'));

});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1" style="width: 50px;" id="hourmain">
<span ng-show="addItem.Hour.$error.pattern">The number must be between 0-4</span>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Hour" ng-model="form.Hour" placeholder="Hour" required="required" ng-pattern="/^[0-4]+(\.[5]{1})?$/" step="0.5" min="0" max="3" maxlength="3" id="hour" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, in **vanilla javascript**, you can grab the specific element using:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[name="Hour"]');
```

and then set the value of the `ng-pattern` attribute, using:

```
input.setAttribute('ng-pattern', '/^[0-9]+(\.[5]{1})?$/');
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[name="Hour"]');
input.setAttribute('ng-pattern', '/^[0-9]+(\.[5]{1})?$/');

console.log('input ng-pattern is now: ' + input.getAttribute('ng-pattern'));
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1" style="width: 50px;" id="hourmain">
<span ng-show="addItem.Hour.$error.pattern">The number must be between 0-4</span>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Hour" ng-model="form.Hour" placeholder="Hour" required="required" ng-pattern="/^[0-4]+(\.[5]{1})?$/" step="0.5" min="0" max="3" maxlength="3" id="hour" />
</div>
```